# NetSuite SCA Trigger User Event

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I wrote a before submit user event script to check a sales order and when a certain condition is present to check a box. Works fine from the NetSuite interface, but orders placed on SCA are not triggering the script. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a checkbox on the script deployment screen that allows the script to be fired from the SCA environment. Note that there may be performance implications of enabling the server side scripts to fire, which is why the checkbox is there in the first place.

Comment: Yup, Gotta say I have seen that and it didn't come to mind, thanks very much your awesome!